# Is there any c library available to check network connectivity?

Tags: open-source, library, c++, networking, c

I need to check the connectivity of a host over a local network using `C` program, I do not wish to use system commands such as `ping`. 
 To check my ethernet I used **gethostbyname()**  which depends on `DNS` server to resolving IP as per my knowledge. 
 I am building a simple c program to check my ethernet functionality where the connection is **pair to pair** and I have assigned the `IP` statically on both the devices.
Is there any C library such as  **netdb.h**  available, which I can use to validate simple ethernet functionality.

Comment: Why bother with DNS? Why not just ping?

Comment: I do not wish to use system default commands(customized rootfs-commands removed), rather I would like to create a custom application similar to ping.

Comment: Life is too short to go reinveting the wheel. Don't you have other stuff to do? Reuse as much as you can, up to 90% of your app, if you can, and concentrate on the stuff which is new & unique to your app.